# selecting top 3 rows in an ordered select

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit, greatest-n-per-group

i have table data like this:

```
id,time,otherdata
a,1,fsdfas
a,2,fasdfag
a,3,fasdfas
a,7,asfdsaf
b,8,fasdf
a,8,asdfasd
a,9,afsadfa
b,10,fasdf
...
```

so essentially, i can select all the data in the order i want by saying something like:

```
select * from mytable ordered by id,time;
```

so i get all the records in the order i want, sorted by id first, and then by time. but instead of getting all the records, i need the latest 3 times for each id.

Answer:

Well, I figured out how to do it. I'm surprised at how quick it was, as I'm operating on a couple million rows of data and it took about 11 seconds. I wrote a procedure in a sql script to do it, and here's what it looks like. --Note that instead of getting the last 3, it gets the last "n" number of rows of data.

```
use my_database;

drop procedure if exists getLastN;
drop table if exists lastN;

-- Create a procedure that gets the last three records for each id
delimiter //
create procedure getLastN(n int)
begin
  # Declare cursor for data iterations, and variables for storage
  declare idData varchar(32);
  declare done int default 0;
  declare curs cursor for select distinct id from my_table;
  declare continue handler for not found set done = 1;
  open curs;

  # Create a temporary table to contain our results
  create temporary table lastN like my_table;

  # Iterate through each id
  DATA_LOOP: loop

  if done then leave DATA_LOOP; end if;
  fetch curs into idData;
  insert into lastThree select * from my_table where id = idData order by time desc limit n;

  end loop;
end//

delimiter ;
call getLastN(3);
select * from lastN;
```

sorry if this doesn't exactly work, I've had to change variable names and stuff to obfuscate my work's work, but i ran this exact piece of code and got what i needed!

Answer (score 7):

I think it's as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `time` DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Ah, I see. People always want such strange things :P

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches that I'm aware of are (1) to use a set of unions, each one containing a "limit 3", or (2) to use a temporary variable. These approaches, along with other useful links and discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from mytable as m1
where (
   select count(*) from mytable as m2
   where m1.id = m2.id
) <= 3 ORDER BY id, time
```

Comment: it's a start...but that query doesn't quite work. i'll take this idea and see if i can get it working.